Can police offer an “immune interview”?
I feel like I heard about this idea somewhere, but I can’t remember if it’s a real thing or what the correct name for it is.
Let’s say Bob was committing a crime, and while doing so, he witnessed Fred committing a worse crime. No one else saw Fred, and the police will not be able to solve Fred’s crime without Bob. Bob wants to help solve Fred’s crime, but he doesn’t want to incriminate himself.
Is there a type of meeting or interview that police can offer where they agree that none of the information gained in the interview will be used against the person they are interviewing? The police would presumably only offer this if they had no other options available, but I’m just asking if it’s something they can do.
I know courts can make immunity deals, but can police set up something like this directly?

In general, the police (in the US) cannot guarantee any sort of leniency or immunity.  Not only is the promise of one police officer not binding against another, the promise will not be upheld against the officer if he is the one who makes the arrest.  Cops might say “I will talk to the judge” or “I will talk to the DA” — and they might talk, but the talk will have no effect on your sentence.

This is called "witness immunity". Usually set up by the prosecution, not the police. In situations like this, Bob would hire an attorney to represent them, and approach the local DA with the proposal to exchange the testimony and evidence for an immunity deal so that Bob wouldn't incriminate themselves through their testimony. If an agreement is signed, Bob then comes in and provides the testimony. See also here and here.
Also, in other countries, called "state's evidence" or "state witness". Sometimes these agreements are also attached to plea bargains, with reduced sentences instead of immunity.

Also note that the police are (from what I’ve read; IANAL) allowed to lie, so attempting this with the police would be very dangerous from what I understand as they could presumably claim to provide immunity, get what they want, and then not follow through.

You should never count on anything the police promise you. However, apparently in at least some US states, if the police falsely promise immunity and the witness believes the promise and testifies, the government is bound by case law to honor it: https://www.hmichaelsteinberg.com/how-far-does-it-go-what-happens-when-the-police-make-promises.html

I think this is pretty much Colorado only. Colorado is basically the only state that has actually bothered to fix the loopholes that police use to violate the law

@OscarSmith, it's not a matter of "bothering" - it's merely a new loophole. A corrupt officer can offer a criminal immunity, thereby forcing the government to honour it.

@RokeJulianLockhart presumably that would result in some negative consequence for the officer, since presumably they are not supposed to offer immunity, so offering it should be a fireable offense (and extremely straightforward to deal with, since if it has effect, then its been proven already in court (since the criminal has gone free))

@bob Though "the police is allowed to lie to you" seems to be a rather uniquely American concept. Here in Sweden the police is very much not allowed to lie, and in contrast police and prosecutors are legally obligated to keep you and your representation (within reason) up to date with what they have on you and what they suspect you did. I think it's similar in most of the Western world.

@BeB00, indeed. However, there has been more than one instance of a well-educated person entering a local constabulary solely to provide assistance to an OCG.

As a side note, a witness who does have immunity loses the ability to please the fifth against incrimination.

@xLeitix. I think that depends on the lie. Police officer asks a drugs dealer for drugs, the dealer asks “are you a police officer”, quite likely he is allowed to lie. On the other hand, they can’t obstruct your defence lawyer by lying about what evidence they have. Can you check if they are allowed to tell two suspects “your friend admitted everything, so it’s best for you to tell us what you know”?

@gnasher729 My knowledge is second-hand (through defence lawyer friends), but I would be surprised if they can. This kind of "you better confess because we already know everything" kind of lie is exactly what they are not allowed to do. They can and will confront you with evidence they have (drip-fed piece by piece to give the suspect ample opportunity to mess up their story), but they cannot say or insinuate that they have more than what they actually have.

@gnasher729 I think your first example (the drug deal "on the streets") falls under what I mean with "within reason". The executive in Sweden is also not stupid.

Presumably what we're talking about is specific to lying to suspects during interrogations. I doubt any country would prohibit lying more generally, as it would put an end to under cover investigations.

This sounds like a "proffer session".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proffer_agreement
"Witness Immunity" just means that the witness won't be charged for some other crime.  A "Proffer Session" is the negotiation where the witness tells what s/he could testify to, if s/he gets immunity.
(I'm not a lawyer, and my knowledge of proffer sessions comes entirely from David Rosenfelt's Open and Shut)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
